# entropy to mnemonic converter

Tags: python, mnemonic-seed

how to make an entropy to mnemonic converter
to read a file with an array line by line
in python or javascript
there

var bip39 = require('bip39')

var mnemonic = bip39.entropyToMnemonic('00000000000000000000000000000000')
console.log(mnemonic)

but I can't figure out how to read from the file
if there is a python easier tell me

Comment: stackoverflow.com must already have excellent answers covering [reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/477035) in either Python or Javascript.

Comment: I know what it is, I don’t understand how to add

Comment: This is more a python programming question, not about BTC so much.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by RedGrittyBlock this is really more of a web development question vs a bitcoin one. Also although it can be fun to create keys from file sources, typically it's a bad idea and should be more of a learning exercise than for actual use. To that end you should look at the built-in [FileReader() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) if you are seeking a simple javascript solution.

For example if you were doing a drag-drop to capture the file

```
holder.ondrop = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(event) { 
    var binary = event.target.result;
    
    //Do whatever you want with the data, sha256 hash it, etc
    
    //var mnemonic = bip39.entropyToMnemonic(binary);
   
  };

  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/coinables/coinables.github.io/blob/master/dragdrop/index.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain it to me in more detail?


holder.ondrop = function(event) {
^
ReferenceError: holder is not defined